# iCloud calendar command line utility

Tags: calendar, icloud

Is there a CLI utility that allows one to sync up with their iCloud calendar (i.e., iPhone calendar on the cloud) to modify calendar events, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is suggested [in this blog](http://niels.kobschaetzki.net/blog/2014/07/24/switching-from-os-x-to-linux/):

> I used a software from http://icloud.niftyside.com/ which I installed on my Uberspace. It was just unpacking it into a directory of the webserver and visiting the site. Then entering my credentials and I got all the URLs.

Answer (score 2):

[khal](https://github.com/pimutils/khal) can be used in combination with [vdirsyncer](https://github.com/untitaker/vdirsyncer), which is able to synchronize with iCloud. Setup takes a while though.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this release note](https://syncevolution.org/blogs/pohly/2014/syncevolution-14992-released) for version 1.4.99.2 from 26 May 2014, syncevolution offers basic iCloud interoperability:

> It now [...] works with iCloud. However, syncing with iCloud ran into a server bug (reported as 17001498 "CalDAV REPORT drops calendar data") and needs further work.